# Forward-Looking HJB: Rewrite as PDV

Tags: continuous-time, bellman-equations

We live in continuous time. Let there be some discount rate $D(t)$, which consists of a discount rate, and some death probability. $V(t)$ contains the flow value of, say, being alive. If you are alive, you get some flow value $A(t)$ every period. I have started at the following discrete-time equation

$$ V(t) = \Delta_t A(t) + \beta(\Delta_t)V(t+\Delta_t)$$

where $\beta(\Delta_t)$ is related to the discrete-time analog of $D(t)$. I have derived, through some reordering of terms, and letting $\Delta_t \to 0$, the following equation:

$$ V(t) = \frac{A(t)}{D(t)} + \frac{V'(t)}{D(t)}$$

Unfortunately, I cannot trust in the flow values $A(t)$ being continuously differentiable, and hence I don't think that $V(t)$ is continuously differentiable. I hence want to rephrase this equation in a way that does not require the derivative $V'(t)$.

I was expecting the resulting $V(t)$ to have the shape of

$$ V(t) = \int_{t}^\infty D(s) A(s) ds  $$

That is, the discounted sum of future fundamental values. Basically, I'm looking for the continous-time equivalent of

$$ V(t) = \Delta_t A(t) + \beta(t)A(t+\Delta_t) + \beta(t)\beta(t+\Delta_t) A(t+2\Delta_t) + \cdots$$

I tried to get there by integration:

$$ \int_t^{\bar t} V'(s) ds = \int_t^{\bar t} D(s)V(s) - A(s) ds \\
V(\bar t) - V(t) = \int_t^{\bar t} D(s)V(s) - A(s) ds
$$

However, this doesn't seem to help into getting it as a present discounted sum. What would be a correct approach here?